# OptionSet Incorrect number or types of arguments (Parameter 'arguments'

Tags: c#

I need to use OptionSet to get args in the console. However I am quite struggling to understand the documentation and the examples I found. LIke this when I am debuging and set the debug to init of OptionSet I see an exception " Incorrect number or types of arguments (Parameter 'arguments') "Could you please advise how to pass the parameters?

http://www.ndesk.org/doc/ndesk-options/NDesk.Options/OptionSet.html

```
  static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
               var dessert = new string[] {PhoneNum = 123456,"Cake","Candy"};
                await Test(dessert);
    
            }

  private static CommandLineOptions GetOptions(string[] args) 
        {
            CommandLineOptions options = new CommandLineOptions();

            var os = new OptionSet
            {
                { "PhoneNum=",  PhoneNum => options.PhoneNumn = PhoneNum },
            };
            
            os.Parse(args);

            return options;
        }

    static async Task Test(string[] args)
        {
            var test = GetOptions(args);
            Console.WriteLine(test.PhoneNum);
        }

 public class CommandLineOptions
    {
        public string PhoneNum { get;set; }
    }
```

Comment: soorry, added a link

Comment: I see. What did you expect the program to output? `Cake` or `Candy`?

Comment: Weel, I need all the parameters, I mean I would set for example "PhoneNum = 123456" {not sure if that's the way to do it} nd then get the 123456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add a `List<string>` property in `CommandLineOptions` to store the rest of the command line arguments (`Candy` and `Cake`), which will be returned by `os.Parse`.

```
public class CommandLineOptions
{
    public string PhoneNum { get; set; }
    public List<string> Rest { get; set; }
}
```

Then, set `Rest` when you parse the args:

```
private static CommandLineOptions GetOptions(string[] args)
{
    CommandLineOptions options = new CommandLineOptions();

    var os = new OptionSet
    {
        { "PhoneNum=",  PhoneNum => options.PhoneNum = PhoneNum },
    };

    options.Rest = os.Parse(args); // Here!

    return options;
}
```

To pass the `PhoneNum` option, you need to prefix with a hyphen (that's how command line arguments work):

```
var dessert = new string[] { "-PhoneNum=123456", "Cake", "Candy" };
```

Then in `Test`, you can get the `Rest` of the arguments:

```
static void Test(string[] args)
{
    var test = GetOptions(args);
    Console.WriteLine(test.PhoneNum);
    foreach (var arg in test.Rest) {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
}
```

I have no idea why you made `Test` and `Main` async.

Comment: thank zou, but the phone number is still nul. all the arguments are in the list

Comment: this is just test for my main code, sorry I kept the methods async as I need them async to perform another operations

Comment: @RDJT Make sure you don't put any spaces around the `=`. That will cause the phone number to not parse as an option.